# int array that reads a file with numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays, file

How do I make this an int array, instead of a string array? I got this as a challenge since I am a beginner programmer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

             string [] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"input.txt"); // <- make this an int array instead.

           
             // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
            System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of input.txt = ");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
            // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
            }   

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");

            // Wait before closing
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Have you look at the … [Int32.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) …  It should help you convert the `string` to an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Select` to map values of a collection.

```
int[] = File.ReadAllLines("c:/myFile.txt")
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
    .ToArray()
```

Here is a shorter "point-free" style syntax:

```
int[] = File.ReadAllLines("c:/myFile.txt")
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for int.Parse(string). It will try to convert a string to an int, throwing an error if it can’t be done. There’s another version called TryParse() that returns a book to check if successful or not to do your own error handling.

You just loop through your lines array and copy the parsed ints into an int array.